# Filling in Bounded Region Mathematica Graph

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, graphing, space-filling-curve

I am trying to shade the regions bound by a function and a horizontal and vertical line. The region  bounded region under the graph where n2[g]>0.3 where g<2^(1/3) to be green and the area where n2[g]>0.3 where g>2^(1/3) to be red. I have code for an image that does this, but the shaded region  also appears to be above the graph. How do I get rid of these circled shaded regions?

The functions and code are attached below. I used a conditional shading function found on a different thread (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37468/conditional-options-in-plot)

[graph of function and shaded regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGUC1.png)

Comment: What I would do is change that from two plots to four plots, one for the left side below 0.3, one for the left side above 0.3, one for the right side above 0.3 and one for the right side below 0.3. I'd omit the filling for the far left and far right. Reading the docs on filling, I can't yet see any way to tell it to only fill above 0.3